# Monaco editor: import zod package type defs

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, monaco-editor, zod

I am trying to integrate [zod](https://zod.dev/) library with [monaco editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) using [this](https://github.com/lukasbach/monaco-editor-auto-typings) auto typings.

Basically I import `zod` type definitions.

But it does not to work correctly with typescript type inference.
For example when I am doing this:

```
import z from "zod";
const obj = z.object({
  a: z.number()
})

type TObj = z.infer<typeof obj>
```

type of TObj is inferred as:

```
type TObj = {
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

while it should be:

```
type TObj = {
    a: number;
}
```

Monaco typescipt version is `4.5.5` which is acceptable. While I tested the same code locally with the same typescript version everything did work as expected.

So my question is why it does not work inside monaco editor and how to fix it?
Basically how to integrate `zod` with monaco ediotor to have correct type inference?

Here is StackBlitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-react-ts-bntgbg?file=src%2FApp.tsx